Accede to particular data inside variable
Suppose I have multiple products, each with a name, number, description, and photos (which could be one or multiple photos).
I want to automatically list the names of the products on the cover page and, on the subsequent pages, display the data for each product one page at a time. For example, if Product 1 has two photos, I want to add the first photo on the first page after the cover page and the second photo on the next page. On these pages, the heading must include the name, description, and number of the product involved.
I know I must do this with the pgffor package, but I have not found any resources on how to create variables like vectors or matrices so I can access them dynamically with a for loop. Is there a way I can achieve this in LaTeX?
Thanks a lot for any answer.

The package datatool might be of interest.
